# Delete class on another click

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I must extra style radio buttons, so i have created span and add class, but aktiv class i can't delete after click on another radio label here is my code:

```
$('.attribute_wrapper div label').click(function(){
    var selectedLabel = $(this).attr('id');
    if($('#' + selectedLabel).data('clicked', true)) {
        $('.attribute_wrapper div #' + selectedLabel + ' span').addClass('radioclicked');
    } else {
        $('.attribute_wrapper div label span').removeClass('radioclicked');
    }
});
```

I can't understand, what's wrong in my *else* statement?

Markup:

```
<div class="attribute_wrapper">
    <div class="attribute_multiselect_single">
        <label id="lblID1">
            <span class="radiobutton">&nbsp;</span>
            <input type="radio" checked="" value="1384" name="color_white" id="color_white103" required="0">White
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show us your markup?

Comment: Where is clicked set?

Comment: My HTML look so: <div class="attribute_wrapper">
  <div class="attribute_multiselect_single"><label id="lblID1"><span class="radiobutton">&nbsp;</span><input type="radio" checked="" value="1384" name="color_white" id="color_white103" required="0">White</label></div>
</div>

I have 18 div's with class "attribute_multiselect_single", i get this with a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it from

```
$('.attribute_wrapper div label').click(function(){
    var selectedLabel = $(this).attr('id');
    if($('#' + selectedLabel).data('clicked', true)) {
        $('.attribute_wrapper div #' + selectedLabel + ' span').addClass('radioclicked');
    } else {
        $('.attribute_wrapper div label span').removeClass('radioclicked');
    }
});
```

to

```
$('.attribute_wrapper div label').click(function(){
    $('.attribute_wrapper div label span').removeClass('radioclicked');
    $(this).find('span').addClass('radioclicked');
});
```

This will remove all `radioclicked` classes from any other `spans` and then apply it to the one you just clicked

Answer (score 0):

you can use `toggleClass()` for this

try this

```
 $('.attribute_wrapper div label').click(function(){
     $(this).find('span').toggleClass('radioclicked');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style radios and checkboxes

HTML :

```
<input type="radio" name="blop" value="0" id="blop0">
<label for="blop0"></label>

<input type="radio" name="blop" value="0" id="blop1">
<label for="blop1"></label>

<input type="radio" name="blop" value="0" id="blop2">
<label for="blop2"></label>
```

CSS :

```
/* Hide the input */
input[type="radio"] {
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0); /* W3C */
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0); /* IE */

    position: absolute;
}

/* Style the label */
input[type="radio"] + label {
    color: #333;
}

/* Style the label for selected radio */
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    color: #f33;
}
```

See this fiddle [jsfiddle.net/9u5wW/](http://jsfiddle.net/9u5wW/)

Comment: $(this).attr('id') == this.id

Comment: if `selectedLabel` is equal to the id of `this`, then `$('#' + selectedLabel)` is just equal to `$(this)`

Comment: Your code does not work because `$('#' + selectedLabel).data('clicked', true)` sets 'clicked' to true for the this element, it's not a comparison